# EntityFramework Core load automatically all dependencies by Id

Tags: entity-framework-core

for classes that evolve quickly in terms of dependencies with plenty of `ForeignKeys` in new classes that are being created iteration after iteration during the development process, is there a way to tell EntityFramework to ***load all the dependencies you find for a given object by Id assuming that there are other objects in new tables with that reference as a ForeignKey?***

Basically what I want to avoid is changing the way of loading the object adding the relevant `Include` every time I have a new dependency.

Comment: Maybe enable lady loading?

Comment: I have already created such function for other task, but for real database it will be a nightmare. Better to do `Include` manually, exactly in needed places.

Comment: OK, will do that, many thanks for your contributions! I was just wondering if I was complicating myself or was something that simply worked out of the box